# ODP app working for Oracle clients 10 and 11

Tags: odp.net

I want to my app to work for target machines where the Oracle client could be 10 or 11.
Is it possible to do it with ODP?

If in my app I reference Oracle.DataAccess.dll from my dev machine (i have ORA client11) - my app works only on target machines with client 11...

If I reference ODP from my client 10 - the app works only for machines with ORA client 10.

Is it possible to develop application(with ODP) which will work for both Oracle client versions 10, 11? I am asking for ORA client versions, not DB versions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest is to build on the lower of the two versions (so `2.102.2.20` or whatever of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`).

In case of machines where the higher version is installed you can install a policy into the `GAC` (Global Assembly Cache). This policy file redirects applications that reference `2.102.2.20` to use the new version of `ODP.NET` (11.xxx.x.x).

With a normal Oracle Client installation this policy file should already be in your `GAC`, but if it's not, you should be able to find it in `ORACLE_HOME\odp.net\PublisherPolicy\2.x.`

You should be able to drag these policy files into your `GAC` (Start > Run > `%systemroot%\assembly`).

As long as the correct policy is in place your app built with version 10 should also run on the machine that has Oracle Client 11 installed.

Note: You can also create such a policy file yourself; take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz32563a.aspx) for more details